# Access Google Drive API v3 with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to access my Google Drive account via their API inside of a Rails application. The idea is that I will store files, but I don't believe I need to implement any authorisation for it (like with `Oauth2`, for example), since I only want to access *my* account.

I have been researching for 2 days, but the Google documentation seems very confused and not very clear.

I started in vain with this guide https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/ruby and tried to co-opt it for use inside of Rails, but since it relies on storing a token file returned upon authentication, I figured this wasn't really the right approach.

I don't have any code to share, just looking for some clarity on how I can achieve what I'm trying to do, or indeed if it's even possible.

*Additional Info:*

I'm using Devise for my own authentication, so implementing `omniauth` through that would be an option if it's necessary. I looked through some documentation around that which Devise has on their side, but I didn't want to go through that (it seemed like a lot) before knowing it was the correct course of action.

Comment: Of course you need authorization to write files to your drive account. But you question is vague. What exactly are you asking. What is not clear about the docs? Did you read the [auth docs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/master/docs/auth.md)?

Comment: I read those docs before, but I think I missed the last section, which looks more like what I need. It's because I don't need authorisation from individual users, because I don't want access to their Drive, I just want their actions to make changes to my own files in my GDrive account. Does that make sense? So API keys aren't enough, and Oauth2 seems over the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests on the Drive API as described on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing). In that link, you can find: «*All requests to the Drive API must be authorized by an authenticated user*».

To complete that authorization process, you should follow the instructions on the [Drive API Ruby Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/ruby#step_1_turn_on_the) linked on your question. Generating and saving a `credentials.json` for later use is the normal approach in this situation. [Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) you can read about using OAuth 2.0 over different scenarios.

I hope to have cleared your doubts on this topic, but feel free to ask further questions.